# How to get or setup dynamic absolute File Path in Visual Studio Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, path

```
string path = @"c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PRACTICE\PRACTICE\Image\Boruto_logo.png";

        if (File.Exists(path))
            MessageBox.Show("Exists");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Not Exist");
```

The code above is a simple program that checks if the full file path exists but what I want is instead of copy-pasting the full path of the file, I want it like the string to be like this >> `string path = "..\Image\Boruto_logo.png"` so that even I transfer my project to another computer it will still run correctly

Comment: Please add more details about the type of project. Is it a Console app, a Winforms app, a ASP.NET MVC website, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and answers i just found out that i can do this `string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\Image\Boruto_logo.png");` Sorry if it is not detailed enough. Im new on this community and dont know much about English Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new `Images` folder in your project folder (this is completely optional) and add your image to it. `Right click to folder` -> `Add` -> `Existing items` -> `Select your image`

[image]

Now change `Copy to output directory` property to **Copy Always**.

[image]

Now use below relative path to access this file.

```
using System.IO;

...
//GetCurrentDirectory() will give you current executable directory.
//Combine with current directory with your resource
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Images\Boruto_logo.png");

if (File.Exists(path))
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Exist");
```

In this way, even if you run your code on another computer it will work fine.

Comment: Thank @PrasadTelkikar it works but it is not a good practice because as more files are added it will make a duplicate of that file which can make my project size bigger. I just found out that I can do this `string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\Image\Boruto_logo.png");` thanks again

Comment: @BlueSilhouette, Thanks for reaching out to me. Soluton which you suggested in comment will work only if you have your source code with you but the solution which I suggested will help you even if you just run your executable